Data Logic at Facade level
I have 2 Db's with their own projects, data services and controllers.
We have methods for them at the facade level which can use either Db.
I have a situation where I need to write something to both Dbs but if it fails on the second one, I need it to rollback on both.
public async Task<bool> DeactivateUser(UserDTO userDTO)
{
    IDbContextTransaction dbOneTransaction = null;
    IDbContextTransaction dbTwoTransaction = null;

    try
    {

        dbOneTransaction = await this.dbOneService.DeactivateUser(mappedUser);
        dbTwoTransaction = await this.dbTwoService.RemoveUserFromLists(userDTO.userId);

        //Commit changes
        if (dbOneTransaction != null)
        {
            await this._dbOneOperations.CommitTransactionAsync(dbOneTransaction);
        }
        if (dbTwoTransaction != null)
        {
            await this._dbTwoOperations.CommitTransactionAsync(dbTwoTransaction);
        }
    }
    catch (DataServiceException ex)
    {
        //Rollback changes
        if (dbOneTransaction != null)
        {
            await this._dbOneOperations.RollbackTransactionAsync(dbOneTransaction);
        }
        if (dbTwoTransaction != null)
        {
            await this._dbTwoOperations.RollbackTransactionAsync(dbTwoTransaction);
        }

        return false;
        }

    return true;
}

I don't see another way to do this as this is the only place I have a scope of both operations. I am aware that the facade shouldn't be performing logic but is there a better way of doing this ?

Transaction management is like security: You shouldn't really try to roll your own. The proposed solution is typical of hand-rolled attempts at transaction management in that it's unsafe.
What happens, for example, if dbOneTransaction completes successfully, but the computer then crashes for another reason than that particular call context's DataServiceException?
As far as I can tell, you now have a completed dbOneTransaction, but no dbTwoTransaction.
And no: Catching any Exception doesn't solve that problem. The computer may crash for other reasons.
In C# the most idiomatic way to deal with transactions is to use a TransactionScope.
That said, if your databases are on two different servers, you'll now need to set up distributed transactions, which is, in my experience, not fun. And first you need to check if the database systems in question support .NET distributed transactions. SQL Server does, and IIRC a few of the other old-guard RDBMSs do, too.
Often, a better alternative is to re-architect the system so that it supports lock-free transactions, typically through some combination of queue-based messaging with retries, idempotency, compensating actions, and eventual consistency. This, however, is not something that can be covered here. Whole books have been written on that topic.
